# JMS corrupting bytes message

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm sending a JMSBytesMessage that I'm reading in from a file. I can write byte array back out to a file with no issues. But if I sent it to the JMS queue and retrieve it and try to print it to a file, it's unreadable.

```
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()))

Files.write(filename, message.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

I've encoded it to Base64, which makes it two KB larger after retrieving it from the queue, but doesn't make it into anything I can read. What don't I understand about BytesMessages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ...strange or incomplete
How do you get the bytes from the JMS message? Is `message` the JMS `BytesMessage` you get from the queue?? There is no `getBytes()`method in class `BytesMessage`.
To get the bytes from a `BytesMessage`, do the following:

```
BytesMessage msg = ... // Obtain the message from the Q
byte[] data = new byte[(int) msg.getBodyLength()];
msg.readBytes(data);
```

Then to write the bytes to a file

```
Files.write(filename, data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Comment: I've voted to close my question because you're right, it IS horribly unclear. Message belongs to a class that wraps JMSBytesMessage. However, your answer saved me. I had forgotten the readBytes line! I was basically reading an empty bytes array, and it weirdly wasn't producing empty files.